# Что нужно изменить или добавить, чтобы сообщение валидации появилось под инпутом?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Все встроенные атрибуты работают в форме, но собственный атрибут не отображает message.

**Класс атрибута**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;



namespace SytePortfolio
{
    public class UserName:RegularExpressionAttribute
    {
        public UserName():base(@"[A-ZА-Я][a-zа-я]{1,29}")
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**Модель**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace SytePortfolio
{
    public partial class UserProfile
    {
        public int IdUser { get; set; }
        [UserName(ErrorMessage = "С заглавной буквы, от 2 до 30 букв")]
        public string NameUser { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "От 1 до 50 символов")]
        public string SurnameUser { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "От 2 до 50 символов")]
        public string MiddlenameUser { get; set; }
        public DateTime? AgeUser { get; set; }
        [StringLength(300, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "От 1 до 300 символов")]
        public string AdressUser { get; set; }
        [EmailAddress]
        public string AmailUser { get; set; }
        [Phone]
        public string PhoneUser { get; set; }
        public int? MainImg { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Форма**

```
<div class="form-group">
   <h6>Имя</h6>
   <input asp-for="@Model.OneUser.NameUser" class="form-control textInput" />
   <span asp-validation-for="@Model.OneUser.NameUser" class="text-danger"></span>
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.OneUser.NameUser, "*")
</div>
```

Comment: [How To Do Custom Validation Using ValidationAttribute of ASP.NET MVC](http://dotnetmentors.com/mvc/how-to-do-custom-validation-using-validationattribute-of-aspnet-mvc.aspx)

Comment: Несмотря на мой ломанный английский прочитал, переделал, однако когда ввожу что то некорректное, ноль внимания, короче не работает сие код. Однако встроенные атрибуты работают. Где то связь нарушена

Comment: вы вводите и форму отправляете на сервер? Или вы ожидаете видеть ошибку прямо сразу после ввода?

Comment: ожидаю увидеть text-danger, до того как нажать кнопку..

Comment: Вы же код на C# пишете, навряд ли он будет на клиенте обработан без нажатия на кнопку. Как просто идея, попробуйте вместо своего аттрибута использовать RegularExpressionAttribute

Comment: Да эта штука работает, просто хотел, для каждого подобного свойства один класс, чтобы не прописывать регулярку в каждом, а просто [UserName]

Comment: будет ли оно работать, если отнаследоваться не от ValidationAttribute, а от RegularExpressionAttribute и прописать в конструкторе вашу регулярку?

Comment: Переделал, но даже при нажатии ничего(сделал правку в коде вверху)